# How to close an image that is displayed by clicking on anchor tag in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, anchor

I want to add a close button to an image that I opened in my Image gallery. I have used the 'img' tag inside the anchor tag, where it should display a particular image of full size within the same page and want to close the image and come back to the main page.

I have came across doing this solution with Jquery, Is there anyway it can be done with javascript??

**index.html**

```
<div class="image-gallery-items">
      <div class="image-gallery-item">
          <a href="/dist/images/myImg.jpg"
          class="thumbnail">
          <span  class="closebtn">&times;</span>
          <img
            src="/dist/images/myImg.jpg">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="image-gallery-item">
          <a href="/dist/images/myImg2.jpg"
          class="thumbnail">
          <span  class="closebtn">&times;</span>
          <img
            src="/dist/images/myImg2.jpg">
        </a>
      </div>
```

Comment: Show the code in jquery, anything in jquery can be down in native javascript.

Comment: I am not familiar with jquery, that's the reason am trying to solve it in JS

Comment: Yea I meant can you find the solution with Jquery and add it in? If not it's fine, but we will have to know how an image goes from the  gallery to full size, do you add a class or something?